# Conversion fails on Empty Dates when querying MongoDB with Spring Repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, date

I'm trying to retrieve a document on MongoBD using this repository:

```
public interface MyObjectRepository extends Repository<MyObject, String>{

MyObject findMyObjectByIdObject(String IdObject);}
```

where MyObject is a simple custom class with no nested attributes, only Strings and some Dates.

When I try to query MongoDB using:

```
    MyObject obj = myObjectRepository.findMyObjectByIdObject("id");
```

I get this error if any of the custom class Date attributes is null, empty or not present as a field in the MongoDb document:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value []
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1814)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1806)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1328)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1313)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2310)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2158)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1926)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:606)
```

I've tried removing all Date (LocalDate, LocalDateTime, Date ....) attributes of my custom class and I am able to retrieve the document without problems.

Is there a way to retrieve documents even if those dates are empty on the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom converter that handles the conversion of `LocalDate` fields

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Component
public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(String source) {
        if (source == null || source.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return LocalDate.parse(source);
    }
}
```

and now you need to register this custom converter in your MongoDB configuration,for example if you are using Spring Boot, you can do this by creating a `@Configuration` class and overriding the `mongoCustomConversions` bean like below

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableReactiveMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableReactiveMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repository")
public class MongoConfig {

    @Autowired
    private List<Converter<?, ?>> converters;

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to use a custom converter with no success but with this implementation it worked 1st try. thanks